# java - casting generics

Tags: java, list, generics, inheritance

I'm having hard time googling this. I found a lot of articles but I can't still solve my problem.

Here is my code:

`List<MyMainClass> mySource = (List<MyMainClass>) session.getAttribute("myAttribute");`

the ***session.getAttribute("myAttribute")*** may return ***`List<MyObject1>`*** or ***`List<MyObject2>`***. Both ***`MyObject1`*** and ***`MyObject2`*** are subclasses of ***`MyMainClass`*** Now I have 2 functions. The first one accepts ***`List<MyObject1>`*** and the other one accepts ***`List<MyObject2>`***. Now Im getting error in eclipse

`The method myMethod1(List<MyObject1>) in the type MyAction is not applicable for the arguments (List<MyMainClass>)`

Comment: Can you add the code where `myMethod1` is defined, and how you are invoking it? It seems `myMethod1` needs a `MyObject1` list, but you are passing it a `MyMainClass` list, which will not be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't safely store different generic types with the same erasure (`List`) in a session attribute. So: don't do it.

Instead either refactor your code so that it is compatible regardless of the list type of that session attribute. This may be hard, but long-term seems less smelly to me. IME, it's generally a smell of poor design when you need to store two things of potentially different type in a single variable.

You could alternately use two different session attributes so that you know which more-specific list type to cast to.

```
List<MyObject1> mySource1 = (List<MyObject1>) session.getAttribute("myAttribute1");
if (mySource1 == null) {
    List<MyObject2> mySource2 = (List<MyObject2>) session.getAttribute("myAttribute2");
    if (mySource2 == null) {
        // ???
    } else {
        // rock and roll
        myMethod2(mySource2);
    }
} else {
    // proceed
    myMethod1(mySource1);
}
```

If you take the latter approach, I'd recommend writing a wrapper object or method that manages those details for you.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. Generics provides only compile time safeguarding. You are trying to pass a more generic type of list to a more specific type of function of type list.

Understand that an instance of `List<MyMainClass>` can hold instances of both `MyObject1` and `MyObject2`. When you call `function1(List<MyObject1>)` this function expects all the elements the list to be of type `MyObject1`. Therefore you cannot pass a list of type `List<MyMainClass>`.

You need to have distinguished variables to store different types of lists.

Answer (score 0):

As advised, this is bit tricky. If you really want to do it, I think you can do this as below:

```
 List<MyMainClass> mySource = 
                           (List<MyMainClass>) session.getAttribute("myAttribute");
 if(mySource != null && !mySource.isEmpty()){
      //Get the first element and check the type
      MyMainClass firstElement = mySource.get(0);
      if(firstElement instanceof MyObject1){
          List<MyObject1> mySourceObj1 = (List<MyObject1>)mySource;
          myMethod1(mySourceObj1);
      }else{
          List<MyObject3> mySourceObj2 = (List<MyObject2>)mySource;
          myMethod1(mySourceObj2);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you change the way you declare **mySource** and your function signature if its possible .

Declare this way:

```
    List<? extends MyMainClass> mySource = (List<MyMainClass>) 

session.getAttribute("myAttribute");
```

And change your function signature from

```
returnType fun(List<Object1> object1List){
}
```

to

```
returnType fun(List<? extends MyMainClass> object1List){
}
```